# Update column to insert spaces in one of the columns in sql server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

How do I achieve the following by a stored procedure or sql script in sql server?

Say for example, I have **a-b** in one of the columns and I need to update that column to **a - b** instead.
How do I insert spaces before and after the dash in existing data in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update TableName set ColumnName = Replace(ColumnName, '-', ' - ') where SomeCondition ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE YourTable
    SET YourColumn = REPLACE(YourColumn, '-', ' - ')
```